# Variables retaining value after program is terminated, how to prevent? C

Tags: c, variables, structure

This is a program that asks the user to input Shipping information about selling bikes, pretty lame.  At the end when it prints out the number of bikes order, and the total cost, the numbers get screwed up.  The previously entered amounts seem to be sticking in the memory.  How do I fix this?  If that is not the problem I would not mind being told so :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//structure
typedef struct
{char cust_name[25];
 char add_one[20];
 char add_two[20];
 }ORDER;

 ORDER order;

int main(void){
fflush(stdin);
system ( "clear" );

 //initialize variables
 double number_ordered = 0;
 double price;
 char bike;
 char risky;
 double m = 359.95;
 double s = 279.95;
    //inputs for order
    printf("Enter Customer Information\n");
    printf("Customer Name: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &order.cust_name);

    printf("\nEnter Street Address: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &order.add_one);

    printf("\nEnter City, State, and ZIP: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &order.add_two);

    printf("\nHow Many Bicycles Are Ordered: ");
        scanf(" %d", &number_ordered);

    printf("\nWhat Type Of Bike Is Ordered\n  M Mountain Bike \n  S Street Bike");
   printf("\nChoose One (M or S): ");
       scanf(" %c", &bike);

    printf("\nIs The Customer Risky (Y/N): ");
        scanf(" %c", &risky);

    system ( "clear" );

    //print order
    printf("\n**********Shipping Instructions**********");
    printf("\nTo: %s\n    %s\n    %s", order.cust_name, order.add_one, order.add_two);

    if (bike == 'M' || bike == 'm')
        printf("\n\nShip: %d Mountain Bikes", number_ordered);
    else 
        printf("\n\nShip: %d Street Bikes", number_ordered);

    if (bike == 'M' || bike == 'm')
        price = number_ordered * m;
    else
        price = number_ordered * s;

    if (risky == 'Y' || risky == 'y')
        printf("\nBy Freight, COD %d\n", price);
    else
        printf("\nBy Freight, And Bill The Customer %d\n", price);


        printf("*****************************************\n");
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: @JesusRamos That tag has been deprecated.  Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1

Comment: @AaronDufour Missed that post, thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the output which you are getting?

Comment: Below answer fixed it, it was a problem with the %d I was using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing `number_ordered` and `price`, which are `double`s, using `%d`. `%d` is only for integer types. Use `%lf` to `printf` or `scanf` doubles.

Comment: Doing that didn't give me crazy numbers! But it did give me all zeroes :(

Comment: Ok, changing number_ordered to an integer and using %d on those worked.  How can I use %lf and not have a crazy string of 0's trailing the number?

Comment: @Church Read your printf documentation ... the answer is there.

Comment: @Church: Checkout [`man 3 printf`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sprintf.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

The formats for both your scanf and your printf are wrong, so you're neither reading nor writing your values properly.